# Google Sites - Portfolio

Tags: ms-office, onedrive

I'm currently creating a portfolio template for students. The portfolio template is supposed to be linked with a program like Dropbox/Skydrive/... (for syncing to desktop) But it also needs to have the functionality of editing .docx files right in the portfolio.

So I'd love an overview of a folder with all files + the .docx files that are editable. Is this an unrealistic idea? Or it is possible to make this?

If yes, how or with which scripts?

Comment: It is very ambitious. I don't think you can do it with any "off the shelf" scripts.

Comment: Probably Windows Live Skydrive?

Comment: No idea then? Is it impossible?